# Python: class instance created in module function not visible from other modules

Tags: python, module

I have to modules, tools.py and env.py. In the tools module I am doing some checks whether certain files exist or not.

Depending on the outcome of these checks I want to initialize an instance of only one of two possible classes inside the env module. I want these instance objects to be part of the env module, since I'd like to import the environment settings from the env module, not from the tools module. That's why I wrote a function creating the instance inside the env module.

tools.py

```
# tools.py
import env

if file_exists == True:
    env.create_env_obj(True)
else:
    env.create_env_obj(False)
```

env.py

```
# env.py

def create_env_obj(file_exists):
global se
if file_exists == True:
    print("Creating environment A")
    se = SetEnvForExistingFile()
elif file_exists == False:
    print("Creating environment B")
    se = SetEnvForNoExistingFile()
```

After the object creation I can actually use the environment object in the tools module but my IDE marks errors everywhere since the import of env had been done before the instance creation.

Also the instance is created inside the scope of that function create_env_obj. So it is not visible to my tools module.
I tried reload but it doesn't change anything.

Now, the thing is that it actually works everywhere but seeing errors all over the place makes me think that I'm deploying bad practice here.
What would be a cleaner solution to archive that?

Comment: Can you just add a dummy `se = None` at the top level of `env.py` to tip your IDE off that that variable exists?  I don't understand the second part of your question about the instance "not being visible to tools".  If you are successfully using it from `tools`, in what sense is it not visible?

Comment: @BrenBarn: That did the trick, I didn't know how to initialize an "empty" instance. Btw, "not visible" did refer to not visible to the IDE, the object did exist and was fully working, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# env.py
se = None
def create_env_obj(file_exists):
    global se
    if file_exists:
        print("Creating environment A")
        se = SetEnvForExistingFile()
    else:
        print("Creating environment B")
        se = SetEnvForNoExistingFile()
```